# ElasticSearch intersection of two queries with same _id

Tags: elasticsearch

I have 2 indexed sets. Let's say that sets have structure like this:

Set1:

```
{ "_id" : "id1",
  "_index" : "index1",
  "_source" :{
     "param1" : "value1",
     "param2" : "value2"
}
```

Set2:

```
{ "_id" : "id1",
  "_index" : "index2",
  "_source" :{
     "param3" : "value3",
     "param4" : "value4"
}
```

I want to make query something like this. Return me joined data with matching id-s where parameters from Set1 are matching some values and parameters from Set2 are matching some other values.

Comment: The only way to do this is in the client code that queries ES after the results has been returned. You can't do `joins` with Elasticsearch

Comment: Thanks for your answer. With that in mind i have reorganised mappings and found solution to my problem. Now I am indexing data from multiple sources under same index with `_update` API from ES. There was just one catch, when indexing, data have to be wrapped inside  `{"doc": data to index }`